# Does QGIS no longer have the option to save a shapefile as WKT file?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, well-known-text

Does QGIS no longer have the option to save a shapefile as WKT file? In the “Geometry” section, there is no option “Well Known Text (WKT)” as the “Type” option. Does any one know why? and if there is any alternative way to create a WKT file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it still has a WKT type option.  You might need to scroll to find it.

[image]